# How can I get metrics from cloudwatch with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get some custom metrics from AWS Cloudwatch with Python, but I'm having some issues. This is the code:

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
client = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name='us-east-1')


response = client.get_metric_data(
   MetricDataQueries=[
        {
            'Id': 'lambda',
            'MetricStat': {
                'Metric': {
                    'Namespace': 'metrics.tcc',
                    'MetricName': 'responseTime',
                    'Dimensions': [
                        {
                            'Name': 'target',
                            'Value': 'target'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'interval',
                            'Value': 'interval'
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'requestId',
                            'Value': 'coldstarts',
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'isColdStart',
                            'Value': 'isColdStart'
                        },
                    ]
                },
                'Period': 60,
                'Stat': 'Maximum',
                'Unit': 'Milliseconds'
            },
        },
    ],

    StartTime = datetime(2018, 10, 8),
    EndTime = datetime(2018, 10, 9)
)

print(response)
```

In the response, I just got a JSON with these elements:

```
[('ResponseMetadata', {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '2217d5b3...', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '2217d5b3...', 'date': 'Wed, 10 Oct 2018 14:31:10 GMT', 'content-length': '483', 'content-type': 'text/xml'}}), (u'MetricDataResults', [{u'Timestamps': [], u'StatusCode': 'Complete', u'Values': [], u'Id': 'lambda', u'Label': 'responseTime'}])]
```

What I'm doing wrong? I will appreciate your help, I've tried a lot of changes, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

empty data means:
 * Either there is no data for the timeframe you requested
 * The data is not available in the period you requested (1min in this case)
 * The metric does not exists with the provided namespace/name/dimensions.

Have you verified that all the above are correct?